# I can't install JDK on on win Server 2008

Tags: java-8, windows-server-2008

As title, i need install JDK on win server 2008 enterprise. But when I run JDK, it not run, it not error. I don't understand why it do. i'm try reinstall jdk 32 bit with my server 64 bit and it was not run.Some body help me?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try installing the 64 bit version of the Jdk?